# Unimplemented __init__()

Tags: python, python-datamodel

I was looking over some code with a misspelled `__init__()` function (it had a total of 3 underbars instead of 4).  And I realized I didn't really know what happens in a Python when an object cannot find a suitable `__init__()`.

Is there a default initializer that is inserted automatically?  Is there a default `__new__` that gets called?  Why does a constructor with arguments fail?

```
class TestClass(object):
    def do_something(self):
        print("Hello From TestClass!")

# What is called here?
instance = TestClass()
instance.do_something()

# Why does this fail?
argument = 100
instance = TestClass(argument)
```

Comment: you inherited `__init__` from `object`.

Comment: @timgeb Still a valid question without the new-style class.

Comment: Anyway, OP has three questions. I think two are good, but the last one isn't so good. The ctor with an argument will fail because there's no argument present in the ctor signature.

Comment: *Why does a constructor with arguments fail?* Why should it succeed?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a default initializer that is inserted automatically?

Yes. There's a default dummy constructor on every class unless overwritten/inherited.

> Is there a default `__new__` that gets called?

Yes. Again by default it doesn't do much except for actually creating the object and setting its type.

> Why does a constructor with arguments fail?

Because the default constructor takes no arguments and does nothing.

Comment: I think you're repeating the OP's confusion of "initializer" with "constructor".  It's his _initializer_ that raised an exception when he passed arguments to it.  Also, classes (without `__init__` or `__new__` defined) don't each have their own "dummy" constructor and initializer, but _inherit_ defaults from an ancestor class (usually `object`).

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Old style classes do not inherit from `object` and they do have dummy `__init__` and `__new__` methods. My statement is still true for new style classes since `object` obviously is not a new style class.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase As for "initializer" and "constructor" I don't really understand what you are talking about. You seem to talk about some language issue which is not the point here. It doesn't matter if you call `__init__` an initializer or a constructor. The statements are still true.

Comment: What do old-style classes have to do with the question?  The author was using only new-style classes.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase That's your assumption based on the snipped OP posted. It is not stated anywhere in OP's question. I cover all possible cases. Plus again: my statements are still valid for new style classes since `object` is an old style class. Dude, what is there that you don't understand? -.-

Comment: The OP got initializer vs. constructor both right and wrong in various places, making it unclear whether he or she understands the difference.  It's a common mistake for new Python programmers, especially if they learned the term "constructor" from another language like Java.  You quoted one of the places the OP got it wrong ("Why does a constructor with arguments fail?") and repeated the wrong word in your answer, which can't help the OP's confusion any.  (The constructor `__new__` is fine, and in fact _requires_ arguments, it's the initializer `__init__` that is raising the exception.)

Comment: "That's your assumption [...]. It is not stated anywhere in OP's question." --- The OP's code has exactly one class, which inherits from `object`, making it a new-style class.  OP could never have asked this question about old-style classes, because they don't _have_ `__init__` or `__new__` methods to ask about.  (Also, in what way is `object` old-style?  It's literally what makes a new-style class "new".)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Dude, old style classes have implicit initializers. Otherwise it would be impossible to initialize them. And `object` **is** an old style class because (by definition) a new style class is a class that inherits from `object`. Obviously `object` **does not** inherit from `object`.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase And again: you are generalizing that he is talking **only** about new style classes based on the snippet. **This is not stated anywhere explicitely**. I have no idea why you are so stubborn on this. Besides, once again: **it does not matter**. The statement is true for **both** styles.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase And if OP is still confused then he can feel free to ask more questions. Do not arbitrarly state what confuses him or not. I find my answer quite clear and your comments being simply picky. Thus I'm done with this discussion. I will answer to OP's questions (if any) though.

Answer (score 1):

Everything inherits from `object` in Python 3 so if no base classes are supplied, defaults will be used for it.

@freakish answered your questions but I'll add a coded example to complement his explanation.

Let's create a new `baseClass` for which our new class `myclass` will inherit:

```
class baseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Inherited __init__ got called")

    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Inherited __new__ got called")
        return object.__new__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

This class overloads `__init__` and `__new__` and so any class which subclasses it will get these methods. Let's create a sample class which inherits from `baseClass` now:

```
class mycls(baseClass):
    pass
```

Empty, no dunders defined. When we create an instance of this class though, we can see `baseClass`'s inherited methods get called:

```
m = mycls()
Inherited __new__ got called
Inherited __init__ got called
```

So as you can see, we'll get everything our parents in the inheritance tree have defined. But, *since classes with no explicit parent always inherit from `object`*:

```
class f: pass    
f.__bases__  # bases gives us the inherited classes

Out[218]: (object,)
```

We will always have these methods to our disposal with default behaviour defined. *For the default `__init__` **this means no arguments**, you need to redefine it in order to customize it!*

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about two frequently confused topics: the initializer `__init__` and the constructor `__new__`.  Also, I think you're confusing Python with languages like Java, where the constructor is a Big Deal and Not Like The Others, and where construction and initialization are mixed up in a single process (and thus a common misunderstanding for programmers new to Python).

In Python, both the constructor and the initializer are methods, no different from any other method. There's a naming convention that (some) methods with double underscores on both ends will be called by the interpreter without you having to do it explicitly, but you could call them yourself if you wanted, and you would get the same results.

In short:  If you understand `__str__`, you understand `__init__` and `__new__`.

(I think the weirdest thing about Python for some experienced programmers is how it *doesn't* ambush you with special cases at every turn.)

**Method Resolution Order**

Python 2.3's [new-style classes](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) look up method names by starting with the object's class, then working through that class's ancestors, until it either finds the name it's looking for or runs out of classes to search.

You can see the method resolution order of any class by looking at its `__mro__` field:

```
>>> TestClass.__mro__
(<class '__main__.TestClass'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> float.__mro__
(<class 'float'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> object.__mro__
(<class 'object'>,)
```

(Python constructs the tuple using the [C3 Method Resolution Order algorithm](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), but it's overkill for a simple case like yours.  C3 is mostly concerned with linearizing a complex, multiple-inheritance graph into a tuple of classes that can be searched in a predictable order.)

Any method lookup, even `__init__` or `__new__`, follows the Method Resolution Order.  For each class in the tuple, Python looks for the string (like `'__init__'`) in its class `__dict__`; if that string present, its associated value --- whatever it is --- will be returned as the result of the method lookup.

In your case, Python looks for `TestClass.__new__`, which doesn't exist, and then `object.__new__`, which does.  It then executes `object.__new__` (with some parameters filled in automatically) to construct your new `TestClass` object.  Initialization with `__init__` is identical, except that you might provide some additional arguments yourself.

Proof (in Python 3):

```
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> A.__init__ is object.__init__
True
>>> A.__new__ is object.__new__
True
>>> A.__repr__ is object.__repr__
True
>>> A.__str__ is object.__str__
True
```

**Arguments to `__init__`**

Your attempt to pass an argument to `object.__init__` failed because that method doesn't take any parameters (aside from `self`, which was already filled in for you).  It looks more or less like this:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        return
```

**Conclusion**

Python does not "create" a default constructor or initializer for your class like (IIRC) Java does.  But it has one of each lying around in the `object` class, so if you don't write your own, you'll inherit them.